# How to find which Process is causing High CPU usage

Tags: linux

Is there any way to find out from terminal which process is causing high CPU Usage ?

It would also be useful to order processes in descending order of cpu Usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn this: Please read `man top`. Normally, running `top` without any options already does this.

Comment: for new users in Linux i recommend `htop`